# Grails deployment to Glassfish and slf4j

Tags: grails, glassfish, slf4j

I am working on a grails app and have been trying to deploy it to glassfish . However, during deployment I get the following error:

From server logs:

```
[#|2013-04-16T07:53:21.540-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=91;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|2013-04-16 07:53:21,540 [admin-thread-pool-7720(2)] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V**
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)

                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
```

……

On my system classpath I have the following files:
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar, slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar.

I believe the problem is that Grails is trying to load the method from slf4j 1.6 (I am on Grails 2.1.0). I want Grails to use its the webapps classpath rather than using system classpath.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you cannot have two versions of the same library in your container, so you need to upgrade the version that's in your classpath to 1.6

Comment: Actually I solved this. To my surprise glassfish respects a weblogic.xml file. What I did was created a weblogic.xml file and added the following line in it: